# Namespaced Rails 'root to:' route not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm reading the Rails Guides on routes ([Routes From The Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)), and I saw the following:

> You can also use root inside namespaces and scopes as well. For
>   example:

```
namespace :admin do   
  root to: "admin#index" 
end   

root to: "home#index"
```

I'm trying to replicate this to see how it works, so in my config/routes.rb file I've got the following code:

```
namespace :admin do
  root to: 'users#index'
end
```

I expected to be able to visit 'localhost:3000/admin' and be directed to the users#index page, but instead I got the error message 'uninitialized constant Admin'.

Am I misunderstanding what the example code is supposed to do, or is there something wrong with what I wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

namespace :admin, would route you to the controller Admin::UsersConroller. If you want to route /admin to UsersConroller, you should use scope instead of namespace.

```
scope '/admin' do
  root to: 'users#index'
end
```

You can read more about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Comment: Right I forgot, brain fart. :-)  

But then what would be the url to the admin namespace's root?  I guess I'm confused about the two root paths, and how they aren't overriding each other.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "admin namespace's root". You can map any url to any action, the root option matches '/' and maps it to the action specified. In this case it matches '/admin/' to 'users#index'(This is equivalent to `match 'admin' => 'users#index'`). However, the 'root_path' function now maps to the new '/admin' url instead of the original '/' path. Thus the override.

Comment: The example code given in the Rails Guides has 2 'root' declarations.  When I say 'admin namespace's root', I mean the "namespace :admin do" block and everything inside it.  The guide states that "You can specify what Rails should route '/' to with the root method", meaning the path for a 'root to' command is always set to '/'.  But since the Guide's example code has two 'root to' declarations, each mapped to a different controller/action pair, how does Rails know which pair to use if I navigate to the '/' path?

Comment: When scoped or namespaced, the root would not actually map to '/' but to '/admin/'. '/' would still refer to the original controller action.